# How to calculate average population for each county across all sub-counties in a sql query access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table (table1) containing:

```
Sub_county_name,
county_name, 
total_pop(for each sub county)
```

I want make a query that gives me the average population for each county across all sub-counties, preferably without join.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT Sub_county_name,county_name,total_pop
FROM table1
WHERE total_pop = (SELECT (SUM(total_pop)/COUNT(county_name)) 
                   FROM table1 a 
                   WHERE a.county_name = table1.county_name);
```

This runs but only gives me two entries (there are 100 counties).

Could I get a hint on what I've done wrong?

Comment: I think your query as it stands will only work for counties with a single sub-county. You need to move the stuff in the where clause up into the select part since you want to retrieve that value, not filter by it.

Answer (score 0):

1)  Just use a group by rather than a join.

2)  You can use the built-in avg() function to get an average (mean).

```
select county_name, avg(total_pop) from table1 group by county_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do an aggregate on county_name, so you'd ignore sub_county_name. It would look like this:

SELECT county_name, Avg(total_pop) AS average_pop
FROM Table1
GROUP BY county_name;

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can I use the same code to calculate variance of the population?If yes,is it better to use Var or VarP?

Comment: The Var and VarP are domain functions which are a little different than the aggregate functions. Var and VarP aren't available as aggregate (Ok, I don't know that for sure, it depends on version of Access), so you would have to use the domain functions. Var returns the sample variance for a field, and VarP returns the population deviation for a field.